# Python VK Api не подключается к longpoll

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, long-poll

Вот код. Вот что выдает. не понимаю что эта ошибка значит и как ее решить.
Причем при ручном подключении без использования модуля vk_api все подключается прекрасно.

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll
import vk_api
import requests
token = "использован_access_token_странички_пользователя_вк"
v = 5.103
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token, api_version=v)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk = session_api)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1438, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Иван/PycharmProjects/vk-tg-bot/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk = session_api)
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\vk-tg-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\longpoll.py", line 517, in __init__
    self.update_longpoll_server()
  File "C:\Users\Иван\PycharmProjects\vk-tg-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\longpoll.py", line 531, in update_longpoll_server
    response = self.vk.method('messages.getLongPollServer', values)
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Что за токен? Токен сообщества? Это важно.

Comment: Токен получен через standalone-приложение на фейк-странице. Указал все разрешения.
Т.е. не сообщества. С сообществом все отлично работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll
import vk_api
import requests

token = "использован_access_token_странички_пользователя_вк"
v = 5.103
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token, api_version=v)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
```

VkLongPool принимает другой аргумент

Comment: Странно, но работает. Хотя не знаю почему, ведь что в документации сказано, что нужен объект VkApi, что на ютубе все через.get_api() делали. Спасибо.